# How does one search within C# classes without previously knowing what's inside?

Tags: c#

I'm sorry if it's confusing, but I don't really know how to word my question.

My C# class is filled with data from API JSON response, it looks as follows:

```
[DataContract(Name = "user")]
public class User
{
    [DataMember(Name="id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to do things like finding an user from `User` object list, based on some data I have.

There are tutorials made by Microsoft about working with classes, [they imply that I know what's inside](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/objects) by storing just added element in a variable.

My issue is that I need to find the `User` (specifically `id`) using `email` - I don't know how to start on this one.
[The other MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/console-webapiclient) shows that I can just iterate through all elements of `User`, and then I suppose I could find the `id` with a simple `if` statement?... No way it's optimal, considering there are over thousand entries.

Comment: So you have a list of users of type `User` and you need to find some users based on some information you have? You could try with Linq as `Users.Where(x => x.Email = "yourEmail");`?

Comment: "No way that's optimal" - why do you think so? If it is slow, you want to do the work asynchronously?

Comment: "No way it's optimal, considering there are over thousand entries." Why shouldn´t this be optimal? If the id is indexed for example this takes only nano-seconds. And even if not: thousands of entires aren´t very much, it shouldn´t take much time anyway.

Comment: Anyway: what do you mean by "what´s inside"? Aren´t your entities allways `User`-objects? Is there any way that a query may return something different then users?

Comment: @ALFA I'm probably doing something very wrong, but your way responds with ```System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereListIterator`1[Program.User]```

Comment: @HimBromBeere I didn't assume a class was actually a DB of sorts. I'm not used to such conveniences, I'm coming from Python. This kind of changes the way I look at it. I also think I really should pick up a proper book.

Comment: @xtl Trying to learn yourself by taking a book or some tutorial is allways a good idea.

Comment: Calling `ToList` on the iterator suggested by ALFA should solve that problem for you.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Ah, key word - iterator. I tried to do something like `var desiredUser = users.Where(x => x.Email == "email@example.com").ToList();`, ended up making a `foreach` expression. It works, but is it really how it should be done in C#?

Comment: If there are multiple users with the same mail, then of course you have to iterate them in some way. Otherwise just use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `Where`, which returns the first element that matches the condition, or null if none was found.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Thanks a lot - it's pretty much what I wanted to achieve.